# Как узнать, сколько памяти занимает пакет?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как узнать, сколько места в оперативной памяти занимает пакет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать следующую оценку:

1. открыть сессию и замерить сколько памяти в PGA занимает данная сессия
2. запустить пакет и сделать новый замер памяти в PGA для данной сессии
3. посчитать разницу

PS посмотреть точно сколько памяти занимает конкретный пакет таким образом не получится - мы можем только оценить на сколько изменился размер занимаемой PGA памяти и только в том случае если мы найдем соотв-ую информацию в `v$mystat`.

В качестве альтернативы можно попробовать воспользоваться пакетом [DBMS_SESSION.GET_PACKAGE_MEMORY_UTILIZATION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sessio.htm#CHDEGEAJ):

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
 o_names dbms_session.lname_array;
 u_names dbms_session.lname_array;
 u_types dbms_session.integer_array;
 u_amnts dbms_session.integer_array;
 f_amnts dbms_session.integer_array;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Owner                          Unit                                 Type       Used       Free');
  dbms_session.get_package_memory_utilization(o_names, u_names, u_types, u_amnts, f_amnts);
  FOR i IN 1 .. o_names.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(o_names(i),30,' ') || ' ' || RPAD(u_names(i),30,' ') || ' ' || LPAD(u_types(i),10,' ') || ' ' || LPAD(u_amnts(i),10,' ') || ' ' || LPAD(f_amnts(i),10,' '));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

пример вывода:

```
Owner                          Unit                                 Type       Used       Free
SYS                            DBMS_SESSION                           11       2320        672
SYS                            DBMS_SESSION                            9        368        616
SYS                            PLITBLM                                 9        192        792
SYS                            DBMS_OUTPUT                            11       2992          0
SYS                            DBMS_OUTPUT                             9        208        776

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Такс, а как посмотреть, сколько сессия занимает в PGA ?

Comment: @lDrakonl, [как-то так](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/my-stats/). Нас интересует: `session pga memory`, `session pga memory max`

Comment: Идея интересная, но пакет так же выставляет контекст. Нет возможности разобраться, что сколько занимает. В любом случае идея интересная, если добавите комментарий о том, что не всегда сработает, приму как верный